# problem in solving equation

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

**this happened to me when I try to get (f) which should equal sqrt(3)/2
is there any problem in my formula or what?**

[image]

```
a = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
b = {{0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0}};
c = 1/Sqrt[3] {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -2}};
Solve[(a.b - b.a) == (2 I c f) , f]
```

I am trying to verify these relation I chose a b c = 4 5 8 
[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site) and [Hints and help on using the site efficiently](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/hints-and-help-on-using-the-site-efficiently) and [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and read the [FAQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: I pasted the code in for you. You get no solution because there is no solution.

Comment: why there is no solution? the solution should be Sqrt[3]/2

Comment: Look at `MatrixForm[(a.b - b.a)]` and   `MatrixForm[(2 I c f)]`, you can see by inspection there is no `f`  to make them equal.

Comment: why does that happened?

Comment: @Jeje Solve[(b.c - c.b) == (2 I a f), f] works but could be just a coincidence.

Answer (score 1):

Is this your desired solution?

```
a = {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}};
b = {{0, 0, -I}, {0, 0, 0}, {I, 0, 0}}; c = 
 1/Sqrt[3] {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -2}};

f = {f1, f2, f3}*IdentityMatrix[3]

Solve[(a.b - b.a) == (2 I c f), {f1, f2, f3}]

(* {{f1 -> Sqrt[3], f2 -> 0, f3 -> Sqrt[3]/2}} *)
```

Comment: f should have one solution Sqrt[3]/2

Comment: @Jeje Zzz then you must find another solution approach